# Hierarchical clustering with NCD as the distance metric

Tags: clustering

I am trying to cluster a bunch of executable files, and I want to use NCD ( normalized compression distance) as the distance metric.
Is there any software package which lets me do that?

Update:
I'm using a python script which produces a distance matrix for example for 4 instances like:

```
[[1.0004239875837764, 1.0004587405627736, 1.0012468878082528, 1.0004537475969288],
 [1.0001477300117407, 1.0003889794346572, 1.0007857384580077],
 [1.0005753695194108, 1.0009174811255472],
 [1.0008124881847325],
 []]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much **any implementation** of hierarchical clustering will allow you to supply a distance matrix. This is totally standard functionality. I.e. you have to:

1.) Compute a distance matrix using NCD

2.) Run hierarchical custering.

3.) World Domination!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Can you tell me how I can do the first step? or direct me to somewhere I can learn. Cuz I usually see none of the implementations have the NCD as metric.

Comment: I have not used NCD myself. Have you tried implementing it? It does not need to exist beforehand, just load the matrix!

Comment: I edited the question. I have matrices like the one that I mentioned in the question. do you know how can I feed them to clustering implementation

Comment: Then you are pretty much done, invoke hierarchical clustering from sklearn.

Comment: does it mater that my matrices are not n*n?